# Checkout not progressing

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm troubleshooting an issue whereby the checkout will not progress past Billing Information. I have checked other similar issues and tried updating payment.phtml to no avail. I notice there is an error saying:

> Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead

Is this causing the issue and if so, how would I go about fixing it? The page is:
http://www.trenddesignsathome.co.uk/checkout/onepage/

I'm new to Magento, so please bear with me.

Comment: Where is the error exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I have check your website and check your checkout process. I have also check console while checkout process.
I have found some bug in your shipping method in console :

**Errors like**

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/tmp/.found/magerror.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/trenddes/public_html/skin/local.php(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 5

Warning: file_put_contents(/tmp/.found/magerror.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/trenddes/public_html/skin/local.php(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 9
```

SO you have file missing in `tmp` folder, file name is `mageerror.txt` . Please solve this after that we can go forward.